# How do I store in SVN my customizations to a public open source project?

Tags: svn, code-organization

I'm working on customizing a couple of open source projects in ways that are very much personalized -- i.e., not appropriate to send the patches back to the maintainers for the public.  One of them is stored in CVS, one in SVN.  I use SVN for my own work.

The CVS project is fine.  I check the tree in to my SVN repository, including the CVS directories.  I can commit all my changes, and still do a cvs update to stay up to date with bug fixes/features of the public project.

How should I work on the SVN project?  Is there a 'best practice' or known procedure for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the section in the documentation on [vendor branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html).

Comment: Great -- I guess that I didn't know the definition of "Vendor Branch" until now  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `cvs` project works since you put it under version control (in `svn`). Why can't you put the `svn` repository under (`svn`) version control, too -- you can with vendor branches like suggested by Michael?

If the answer is *"because it is messy and doesn't look right"* you came to realize the (aesthetic) limitations of non-distributed version control. I would suggest you look into what distributed version control systems (DVCS) like [`git`](http://git-scm.com/), [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com) or [`bzr`](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/) can offer you. You will find out that e.g. `git` will make it very easy to maintain your patchset on top of the upstream repository. You would just maintain a private branch of the code, using e.g. [git rebase](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) to forward your changes. All these DVCS's come with some ways to interact with upstream `cvs` or `svn` repositories.